# Allow anonymous users and authenticated users to same route

Tags: symfony, authentication

On some of my pages, I would like to show enhanced content for users that are authenticated. Is this possible? More specifically I'd like to show enhanced content to authenticated users on the "support" firewall.

I am not using the FOSUserBundle (but I could if need be). I'm using Symfony 2.7.5

```
firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:  ^/Login$
        security: false

    support:
        pattern:  ^/Support
        anonymous: ~

    home:
        pattern:  ^/$
        anonymous: ~

    account_create:
        pattern: ^/Account/Create$
        anonymous: ~

    secured_area:
        remember_me:
            key:      "%secret%"
            lifetime: 604800    # One week
        pattern:          ^/
        form_login:
            provider: local_auth
            check_path: login_check
            login_path: login

        logout:
            path:   logout
            target: /
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do something like this in a template:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    {% include 'someothertemplate.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

You have control over whatever role is assigned.  Documentation available [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#book-security-template).

Comment: This is possible, but it is even better if you make these kind of decissions in your controller (using `$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')`). Templates should handle as little business logic as possible

Comment: To expand on @CarlosGranados suggestion, you can use `$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted(...)` to build an array of templates that could then be displayed using `{% for template in templates %}`

Comment: This doesn't work. There is no auth token if you don't have a firewall configured. I can configure one and set the value to anonymous to allow non-authenticated users in, but then the permissions don't flow through correctly.